# Отправить данные на определенный сайт и обработать ответ. libcurl

Tags: c++, google-chrome

Хотелось бы через libcurl отправлять свой Unicode текст и получать ответ на вот этом сайте https://www.dcode.fr/unicode-coding.

```css
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
 CURLcode code;

 curl_slist* list = nullptr;

 list = curl_slist_append(list, "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
 list = curl_slist_append(list, "content-length: 66");
 list = curl_slist_append(list, "accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
 list = curl_slist_append(list, "cookie: PHPSESSID=3323cac7000a759fb892954066845418; _ga=GA1.2.1359388333.1562388670; _gid=GA1.2.2102115529.1562388671; SERVERID108284=104013");
 list = curl_slist_append(list, "referer: https://www.dcode.fr/unicode-coding");
 list = curl_slist_append(list, "origin: https://www.dcode.fr");

 if (curl)
 {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.dcode.fr/unicode-coding");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 YaBrowser/19.6.1.153 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, fopen("cookie.txt", "w"));
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, fopen("cookie.txt", "w"));
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "tool=unicode-coding&ciphertext=%5Cu0442%5Cu044012&output=hexadecimal");
  code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  if (code == CURLE_OK)
  {
   std::cout << "OK";
  }
  else
   std::cout << "NO";
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
 }
 getchar();
```

Приходит просто код страницы, как будто бы POST запрос не отправляется. Форма такая: `tool: unicode-coding
ciphertext: text
output: hexadecimal`

Comment: Там стоит защита с помощью Recaptcha. Плюс CSRF-токен передается в заголовках запроса. Вы уверены, что вам действительно нужно отправлять туда запрос, весь все алгоритмы, представленные на сайте, можно реализовать без особого труда самому?

Comment: Просто хочется разобраться

Comment: Запрос должен идти на адрес `https://www.dcode.fr/api/`

Comment: `<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Если поменять на `/api/`